# Problem ins spinner : it is not showing the selected item

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, spinner, alert

so here is my problem ...
I'm trying to implement a spinner inside my an alert dialog (in kotlin)
the items are displayed just fine, but my main problem is i can't get the selected item, and when i use println insted of the toast, i get the following : "InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed"

Here is the code of MainActivity

```
button.setOnClickListener {

            val view = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext).inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_popup,
                null
            )

            view.spinner01.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {

                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        resources.getStringArray(R.array.planet)[position],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                        .show()
                    spinner01.setSelection(position)
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                }
            }

            val alert = CustomAlert()
            alert.showDialog2(this)
        }
```

here is the code of the class CustomAlert

```
class CustomAlert {

    fun showDialog2(activity: Activity?) {

        val dialog = Dialog(activity!!)

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_popup)

        val dialogButton: Button = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.button3) as Button
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

and here is the ressources

```
<string-array name="planet">
        <item>option1</item>
        <item>option2</item>
        <item>option3</item>
    </string-array>
```

XML FILE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutDescription"
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="283dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView30"
            android:layout_width="87dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Desciption"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.048"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner01"
            android:layout_width="352dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:entries="@array/planet"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView30"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView30" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="351dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFCB00"
            android:text="Envoyer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner01"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner01"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner01" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code.

```
//custom_dialog_view.xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
android:paddingVertical="30dp">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/planet"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Submit"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner01" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


// This is activity code
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
    showDialog()
}

private fun showDialog() {
    val dialogView: View = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_view, null)
    val spinner = dialogView.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner01)
    AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
        setView(dialogView)
        dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitBtn).setOnClickListener {
            val selectedOption = spinner.selectedItem.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this@TestActivity, "$selectedOption", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        this.create().show()
    }
}
}
```